# touchegg trackpad gestures stopped working after upgrading to 17.04

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, 17.04, touchegg

On 16.10 I set up [touchegg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/touchegg) to change the workspace when swiping with three fingers. It worked perfectly until I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty Zapus.
My trackpad still works right now, it's just anything above two fingers that doesn't seem to work.

It's a `ELAN0501:01 04F3:3040` touchpad on an Acer Swift 5. When running `xev`, it doesn't respond to three fingers or more, but it does to two.

I did not change anything in my `touchegg.conf` file before upgrading.
Here is the output of `xinput list-props <trackpad_id>`:

```
Device 'ELAN0501:01 04F3:3040 Touchpad':
Device Enabled (140):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (142): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (270): 1
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (271):   2.500000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (272):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (273):    12.500000
Synaptics Edges (274):  127, 3066, 104, 1826
Synaptics Finger (275): 25, 30, 0
Synaptics Tap Time (276):   180
Synaptics Tap Move (277):   164
Synaptics Tap Durations (278):  180, 180, 100
Synaptics ClickPad (279):   1
Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (280):  0
Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (281):    282
Synaptics Two-Finger Width (282):   7
Synaptics Scrolling Distance (283): -74, -74
Synaptics Edge Scrolling (284): 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (285):   1, 1
Synaptics Move Speed (286): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.053619, 0.000000
Synaptics Off (287):    2
Synaptics Locked Drags (288):   0
Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (289):   5000
Synaptics Tap Action (290): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
Synaptics Click Action (291):   1, 0, 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling (292): 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (293):    0.100000
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (294): 0
Synaptics Circular Pad (295):   0
Synaptics Palm Detection (296): 0
Synaptics Palm Dimensions (297):    10, 200
Synaptics Coasting Speed (298): 20.000000, 50.000000
Synaptics Pressure Motion (299):    30, 160
Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (300): 1.000000, 1.000000
Synaptics Resolution Detect (301):  1
Synaptics Grab Event Device (302):  0
Synaptics Gestures (303):   1
Synaptics Capabilities (304):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
Synaptics Pad Resolution (305): 32, 32
Synaptics Area (306):   0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Soft Button Areas (307):  1596, 0, 1582, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Noise Cancellation (308): 18, 18
Device Product ID (267):    1267, 12352
Device Node (266):  "/dev/input/event9"
```

Hope you can point me in the right direction towards solving this issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

I followed the "preparation steps" on this website from `Install older version synaptics driver that is compatible with xSwipe.` until `That's it for preparation.`: https://github.com/iberianpig/xSwipe#install-older-version-synaptics-driver-that-is-compatible-with-xswipe.

So basically, the solution was to install an old driver for the trackpad.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my Ubuntu 16.04.
Solved by following Robbert's answer that is by installing xSwipe but this didn't end for me there I had to do more configuration. For me I had to set my synclient property ClickFinger3 to 0 [using $synclient ClickFinger3=0 ] to make it work. 
To make 3 fingers swipe work after installing and configuring xSwipe check-out this link https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/TouchpadSupport.